# Testing sqlite for Xamarin PCL

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have some troubles by trying to find a solution to test my Xamarin PCL sqlite Connections.
How could i make i.e. Connection tests for by sqlite for my platforms(at the Moment 2 (Phone 8, Android))?

I tryed to implement sqlite based by this example:
https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

Comment: I 've already find a solution and this is to divide the solution. I adapted the SqlInterfaceImplementation to run on X86 so that I have my own normal C# Win32 test project and so i can test all the logic or controller bottom up to the GUI. Only the View is separately to test.

Comment: In the link below you can find a genius approach for Xamarin and SQLite.
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/tree/master/src

Comment: You can answer your question, please do it with code to help others (like me) ;)